# get value of an attribute of the clicked element

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<ul id='langs'>
   <li data-val='en'>english</li>
   <li data-val='fr'>francais</li>
   <li data-val='it'>italiano</li>
</ul>
```

when the user clicks on any of these `<li>` I want to `alert()` it's data-val attribute value

anybody knows how?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

### Original answer - 2011

```
$('li').click(function () {
    alert($(this).data('val'));
});
```

See [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/UcHuD/).

### Update - 2017

Keep in mind that if you want to use the ES6 [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) syntax, you cannot use `this` and you need to use `e.currentTarget` instead, where `e` is the event object passed as the first parameter to the event handler:

```
$('li').click(e => alert($(e.currentTarget).data('val')));
```

See [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rsp/67a75j3b/1/).

Comment: Nice. Just discovered html5 data attributes are now accessible using the data method.

Comment: the arrow function syntax is clutch, been wondering how to handle this for these kinds of situations

Answer (score 20):

This should do the job:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#langs li').click(function() {
    alert($(this).attr('data-val'));
  });
});
```

Have a look at the [Docs](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Answer (score 5):

```
$('li').click(function() {
    alert($(this).attr('data-val'));
});
```