# attr value in table element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with attr which I don't know how to get:

```
<ul id="myTable" >
    <li><span data-myData="01">first value</span></li>
    <li><span data-myData="02">second value</span></li>
</ul>
<button id = "myButton"> click me </button>
```

in jQuery, when element is selected and clicking the button:

```
$(document).on('click', '#myButton', function() {  
 var tableLength = $('#myTable li').length;
 for(var m=0; m<=tableLength; m++){
     if($('#myTable li' + ":nth-child(" + (m+1) + ")").hasClass('selected')){
        var valor = $('#myTable li' + ":nth-child(" + (m+1) + ")").text(); //works
        var id = $('#myTable li' + ":nth-child(" + (m+1) + ")").attr("data-myData"); // doesn't work
  
     }
   } 
});
```

How can I get the value?

Comment: where is ur table in html??

Comment: the id of the ul is `myTable`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get value of an attribute of the clicked element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205411/get-value-of-an-attribute-of-the-clicked-element)

Comment: so it is not a table , it is <ul>

Comment: The `data-myData` attribute is on the `span`, not the `li`. I'd also suggest you look in to the `each()` method as you can tidy that code up quite easily

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the data-id attribute?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309926/how-to-get-the-data-id-attribute)

Comment: [this might help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12226311/get-value-of-a-custom-attribute-using-javascript-or-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue with your code is that the `data` attribute is on the `span`, not the `li`, hence your code returns `undefined`.

Also note that you can tidy your code up with the use of `each()` and the `:gt` selector to avoid the first `li` in the `ul`. Try this:

```js
$(document).on('click', '#myButton', function() {
  $('#myTable li:gt(0)').each(function() {
    var $li = $(this);
    var valor = $li.text();
    var id = $li.find('span').data('mydata'); // note data() and lowercase property name
    
    console.log(valor);
    console.log(id);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="myTable">
  <li><span data-myData="01">first value</span></li>
  <li><span data-myData="02">second value</span></li>
  <li><span data-myData="03">third value</span></li>
</ul>
<button id="myButton">click me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

With this `#myTable li' + ":nth-child(" + (m+1) + ")` you select the `li` not the `span`. The jquery text function works on li, actually it rewrite the li's content and remove the span inside.

Change this`#myTable li' + ":nth-child(" + (m+1) + ")"` into this `#myTable li' + ":nth-child(" + (m+1) + ") span"`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly : It's not a table. UL is a list.

Secondly : Simple search, simple answer : [Get the pure text without HTML element by javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6743912/get-the-pure-text-without-html-element-by-javascript)

Thirdly : Keep your JS simple!

```
var allSpan = $('#myTable li span') // Contain all span
allSpan.each(function() { console.log(this.innerHTML+ " | "+ this.getAttribute("data-myData")) });
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all it is not a table , it is `<ul>` ,Please find below the snippet and change attribute to lowercase as in snippet

```js
$('span').click(function() {
    alert($(this).data('mydata'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="myTable">
  <li><span data-mydata='01'>first value</span></li>
  <li><span data-mydata='02'>second value</span></li>
  <li><span data-mydata='03'>third value</span></li>
</ul>
<button id="myButton">click me</button>
```

Same you can use for button

Answer (score 0):

You can use .map

```
 $("#myTable li span").map(function() {
    var a = $(this).attr("data-myData");
    alert(a);
 }).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code .it will work definetly:

```
   $(document).on('click', '#myButton', function() {  
     $.each('#myTable li',function(i,v){
       if($(this).hasClass('selected'))
            {
                 var valor = $(this).find('span').text();
                 var id = $(this).find('span').attr('data-myData');
            }

     });
  });
```